# Setuid for iphone app to run as root

Tags: ios4, root, setuid, chown

Im am trying to make my iphone app run as **root**, and i was told to **setuid,** I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow Apple's development guidelines, you can not run the application as root, and you can not access any resources outside of your your own application space, called its "application home directory".

The application home directory is made up of the following:
(1) myApp.app (the bundle — code-signed, and un-changeable)
  - myApp, mainWindow.xib, somepicture.png, etc
(2) Documents
 - files created at run-time, after installation
(3) Library
 - caches, preferences, etc

In order to access any resources outside of those, you'll need to call their iOS API's.

This compartmentalization of the applications is a core part of Apple's security model.  It makes package management much easier, and it is much safer than if applications had root-level permissions across the filesystem.

Alan